# Create an array of promises in $q.all() from json object string values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a bunch of functions that are loaded via services that need to be executed from a `$q.all([funcA(),funcB(),funcC()])`.  And then I have json file which tells the script which services to process.  The problem I have is getting the json value to be saved into an array that that can be passed to the `$q.all(doFuncs).then` where the values of the array will be processed as functions.

The functions, as mentioned, are loaded from various services.  Technically, each function is a promise, but for simplicity I state them as a function here:

```
function funcA() {
 // do something
}
function funcB() {
 // do something
}
function funcC() {
  // do something
}
```

The json file which is dynamically loaded from a remote server will allow me to turn on/off different vendors to be processed as needed:

json:

```
var vendorObj = { 
   "vendorA" : {
      "cName" : "Foo Company",
      "active" : 1,
      "funcName" : "funcA"
   },
   "vendorB" : {
      "cName" : "Bar Company",
      "active" : 0,
      "funcName" : "funcB"
   },
   "vendorC" : {
      "cName" : "FooBar Company",
      "active" : 1,
      "funcName" : "funcC"
   }
}
```

Looping through the json if "active == 1", then add the function name to an array.

```
var doFunctions = [] ;
for (var key in vendorObj) {
   if (vendorObj[key].active == 1) {
      doFunctions.push(window[vendorObj[key].funcName]) ;
   }
}
```

If I process them like in this for loop it works, the added/active functions are executed properly:

```
for (var x=0;x<doFunctions.length;x++) {
   doFunctions[x]() ;  
   //even as promises this works, they are just processed individually
}
```

However, in `$q.all()` when manually defined, the functions are passed in an array as '$q.all(**[funcA(),funcC(),funcG()]**).then(function(response) { ... })'

So the problem I am having is how to pass `doFunctions` so each value is auto-recognized as a function as I am not able to add the `()` after each array value when simply just stating the array name as in the following:

```
$q.all(doFunctions).then(function(response) {
   // process `response`
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a hash that references the functions:

```
var hash = { 
    "funcA": funcA,
    "funcB": funcB,
    "funcC": funcC
};

function funcA() {
 // do something
}
function funcB() {
 // do something
}
function funcC() {
  // do something
}
```

Then lookup the functions in that hash:

```
var promiseArr = Object.values(vendorObj)
                 .filter(_ => _.active == 1 )
                 .map(_ => hash[_.funcName]() );

$q.all(promiseArr).then(function(responseArr) {
     //process responseArr
};
```

Comment: This works!  Is there any other way of doing it so I don't have to maintain the hash object?  In theory Amir's solution above should work but its not - it also follows the same logic in this thread: https://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/ - whats different between the two?

Comment: The sitepoint article declares the functions on the global scope and uses a property accessor on the global object (`window`). This pollutes the global namespace and can create difficult to find bugs from other code using the same names. The advice from the sitepoint article is rubish. Use a property accessor on a private object.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are pushing a reference to the function, not the promise you are trying to resolve.
Try the following:

```
var doFunctions = [] ;
for (var key in vendorObj) {
   if (vendorObj[key].active == 1) {
      doFunctions.push(window[vendorObj[key].funcName]()) ;
   }
}
```

Your doFunctions array now contains promises, and not functions.

Comment: adding the `()` to the end returns this error: `TypeError: window[vendorData[key].fName] is not a function`

Comment: Of what type is `window[vendorData[key].fName]`?

Comment: its a text string value from a JSON object - as shown above in orig post.  I need someway of reading the object value that is a string to be stored as a function in an array.

Comment: your solution follows the same logic from this thread, so I don't understand why its not working when in theory it should be.  I also tried just saving the object value to its own variable `var tVar = window[vendorObj[key].funcName] ;` and then doing `doFunctions.push(tVar()) ;` and still get same error.  https://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/

Comment: Are you sure that the window object exists in your execution? In node, there is only the global object (no window). Unfortunately, scoped functions would not be found in the global object so you would not be able to retrieve them from a string. The original question tried to retrieve a reference of the function from the window object, so I assumed it was available.